Error code 13 training with document processor
Processor type: Custom extractor
I'm having the following error when trying to train a document ai processor:

{
  "code": 3,
  "message": "Invalid document.",
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
      "reason": "INVALID_DOCUMENT",
      "domain": "documentai.googleapis.com",
      "metadata": {
        "num_fields_needed": "1",
        "field_name": "entities.text_anchor.text_segments",
        "document": "gs://pit-vertexai/notas-fiscais/TREINAMENTO 20.05.2024/test.pdf",
        "num_fields": "0",
        "annotation_name": "produto/quantidade"
      }
    }
  ]
}


In the audit log it only shows the following message:
The replica workerpool0-0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs: LINK
When I try to access the link it gives a permission error.
Note: there are currently 1916 training documents.
There's nothing I can do because the error is generic.
Yesterday I had another error:

{
  "code": 3,
  "message": "Invalid document.",
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
      "reason": "INVALID_DOCUMENT",
      "domain": "documentai.googleapis.com",
      "metadata": {
        "num_fields_needed": "1",
        "field_name": "entities.text_anchor.text_segments",
        "document": "gs://pit-vertexai/notas-fiscais/TREINAMENTO 20.05.2024/test.pdf",
        "num_fields": "0",
        "annotation_name": "produto/quantidade"
      }
    }
  ]
}


It was strange because an error was occurring in the documents that had already been trained previously. To resolve this previous error, I changed the document attribute from "Training" to "Not assigned", so these errors stopped, but now I have this other error!
